# c++11 get current time with microsecond precision

Tags: c++, c++11, ctime

I know how to get current time with microsecond precision under linux using gettimeofday(). However it's not portable and does not work on MinGW. How to get the same functionality with C++11?

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main(){
    timeval curTime;
    gettimeofday(&curTime, NULL);

    unsigned long micro = curTime.tv_usec;
    printf("micro is: %lu\n", micro);

    char buffer [30];
    //localtime is not thread safe
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime((const time_t*)&curTime.tv_sec));
    printf("buffer is: %s\n", buffer);

    char currentTime2[30] = "";
    sprintf(currentTime2, "%s.%06Lu", buffer, micro); 
    printf("currenttime is: %s\n", currentTime2);
}
```

it's fine in Linux and does not print buffer under MinGW. What is wrong here?

Comment: Any OS in particular?

Comment: `auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();` You can extract at whatever resolution you want.

Comment: @red asking for it in `ns` does not give you `ns` resolution.

Comment: @Yakk That's true, though it will at least give it to you in a `ns` format. The problem with using a HR clock is that it is not guaranteed to be tied to the system clock (it will pick a `steady_clock` if that has higher resolution), which makes it unreliable for getting the time of day.

Comment: Needing the time with sub-millisecond precision is generally a red flag. Usually the only thing needed with such precision is a time _interval_. The absolute time only matters when comparing that time to times from other clocks, which implies network communications. Networks typically have millisecond-scale latencies.

Answer (score 2):

`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`.  It is portable, but may suck.  Duration cast into high precision: you can even ask how precise it claims to be, but that may not be trustworthy.

`boost` has clock and time libraries that are portable, and may be more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried std::chrono::high_resolution_clock ? 
You might find this [article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1881386&seqNum=2) a useful reference for the inner working of 
C++ 11 chrono library.

Comment: I have that book, still unable to find example to get time. high_resolution_clock does not have to_time_t()